# Adding an array of objects to an Angular scope object -- TypeError

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm getting this error:  "TypeError -- cannot set property 'select' of undefined" in the promise for a repository function.

The variable ***obj*** contains an array of objects.

```
.then(function (obj) {
   // this works...
   var abc = {};
   abc.title = "hello";
   abc.obj = obj;

   // this doesn't work...
   $scope.modelData = {};
   $scope.title = "Import";
   $scope.message = "Please select a Purchase Request"
   $scope.select = obj; // <-- TypeError -- cannot set property 'select' of undefined'
```

It's raising the error during an angular function so I'm sure it's Angular that doesn't like it.

=== Edited to include more code.

Here's the relevant bits of my controller:

```js
var app = ipoModule.controller("ipoController", 
                               function ($scope, $compile, $window, $http, $q, $log, ipoRepository, $routeParams, limitToFilter, $modal, ngTableParams) {

  $scope.ipoRepository = ipoRepository;

  //... not-relevant stuff

  $scope.PRList = ipoRepository.getMvpPRs($scope.POHeader.warehouseId)
            .then(function (obj) {
                var modelData = {};
                modelData.title = "MVP Import";
                modelData.message = "MVP Purchase Request ID";
                modelData.select = obj;
                $scope.modalData = modelData;

                // then do more stuff but it breaks before that...
            })
        .catch(function (err) {
            $scope.HandleErrorDoc('Search Error', err)
        });
})
```

and here's some of my repository

```js
ipoModule.factory('ipoRepository', function($resource, $http) {

  var genericGet = function(params, URL) {
    return $http.get(URL, {
      params: params
    }).then(function(res) {
      if (res.data) {
        return res.data;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    });
  };

  return {
    getSearchResults: function(txt, chk, myPO) {
      return genericGet({
        SearchText: txt,
        excludeCompleted: chk,
        MyPO: myPO
      }, '/Search/GetSearchResults');
    },

    getMvpPRs: function(id) {
      return genericGet({
        id: id
      }, '/MvpUtility/GetMvpPRs')
    }
  }
});
```

... and now the module ...

```js
var ipoModule = angular.module('ipoModule', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'ngGrid', 'ui.bootstrap', 'unsavedChanges', 'ngIdle', 'ngTable'])
  .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, unsavedWarningsConfigProvider) {
    //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    unsavedWarningsConfigProvider.useTranslateService = false;
  });
```

Comment: Can you add a larger code snippet? Is `$scope` being injected?

Comment: Sounds like `$scope` is undefined.  Show us the rest of your controller

Comment: could you please add console.log(obj) ? Something is problem in obj.

Answer (score 0):

I came to the conclusion that Angular couldn't figure out how to handle an array of objects so I tried to create the object as a regular javascript variable first and then assign it to a scope variable ... and it worked.

I'll leave this unanswered though because there may be an "angular" way to do this which I am not aware of.

```js
        $scope.PRList = ipoRepository.getMvpPRs($scope.POHeader.warehouseId)
            .then(function (obj) {
                var modelData = {};
                modelData.title = "MVP Import";
                modelData.message = "MVP Purchase Request ID";
                modelData.select = obj;
                $scope.modalData = modelData;
```

and here's a sample of what is returned in my obj variable:

```js
[
  {
    "prid": "0000",
    "description": "PR0000 - j11-v1 test - youngm Jan 11"
  },
  {
    "prid": "0001",
    "description": "PR0001 - j11-v1 test - youngm Jan 11"
  },
  {
    "prid": "0004",
    "description": "PR0004 - j11-v1 test - j20-contractor Jan 20"
  },
  {
    "prid": "0005",
    "description": "PR0005 - tigerdirect  - yeungm Mar 01"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I see modelData and modalData in your example.
I assume you wrote smth like

```
$scope.modelData = {};
$scope.modalData.select = [];
```

But it's impossible to say without full version of broken code.

Or, you miss $scope injection in first version of code.
Anyway, issue is not angular related.